# Maven testcases are not invoking AspectJ Aspects

Tags: aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have added the Junit test case to call a method with Annotation which in turn have the Around aspect. When i run the `mvn test` command, The Aspect is not getting invoked for some reason.

But when i build the jar using `mvn package` and run the jar, the Aspects are getting invoked.

Here is the code - https://github.com/chandru-kumar/aop-example

Can anyone help on this? How can i make the Aspects invoked for `mvn test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests would work if you would test against the **application classes**, which have been compiled by the AspectJ compiler. But you are trying to test the aspect against a **test class**. That is also possible, but in that case you need to tell AspectJ Maven to actually take care of compiling test classes, too:

```xml
<execution>
  <goals>
    <goal>test-compile</goal>
    <goal>compile</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

P.S.: Thanks for providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most StackOverflow newbies forget that. It helped me to easily identify the problem, in this case without even cloning the repository. But sometimes it is not that simple, then I need to compile and run the example program. Anyway, keep up the good practice!